# How to remove last numbers of string with different lengths C#

Tags: c#, string, trim

NOTE: The lengths of the last 2 is different. So Length-1 doesn't work(right?)

How do I remove the last numbers from example:

> ABStreet 10 552896
>
> ACLane 1520 155

So that it outputs:

> ABStreet 10
>
> ACLane 1520

It probbably is already asked somewhere, and I though of TrimEnd, but I can't seem to get the correct code.

Comment: No, it is not. it is something I tried, just playing around :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a simple Regex expression

```
List<string> elements = new List<string>() {"ABStreet 10 552896","ACLane 1520 155"};

Regex r = new Regex(@"\d+$");
foreach(string s in elements)
    Console.WriteLine("[" + r.Replace(s, "").Trim() + "]");
```

This simply matches any sequence of digits that is at the end of the string and remove it (also trimmering away the last space)

Answer (score 1):

Using Regex it would look like this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string test = "ABStreet 10 552896";

        test = Regex.Replace(test, @"\s\d*$",string.Empty);
        Console.WriteLine(test);
    }
}
```

Or with TrimEnd:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string test = "ABStreet 10 552896";

        test = test.TrimEnd('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0').Trim();
        Console.WriteLine(test);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var x = "ABStreet 10 552896";
var y = "ACLane 1520 155";
Console.WriteLine(x.Substring(0, x.LastIndexOf(' ')));
Console.WriteLine(y.Substring(0, y.LastIndexOf(' ')));
```

Answer (score 0):

This does the job:

```
string test = "ABStreet 10 552896";
string testWithoutLastNumber = test.Substring(0, test.LastIndexOf(' '));
```

I'm just not sure if it is the most elegant and/or effective way to do it. The `LastIndexOf` method looks for the last occurrence of a whitespace (or whatever character separator you wish to use), and then the `Substring` up to that position is taken. The separator itself is not included due to the first character in the string being at position/index `0`.